# How to extract folder name and assign it to a list and file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a set of folders, and each folder contains number of images. Each image has an inrelevant name. But the folder that contains these images has a relevant name.

How extract folder name and assign it to each image?

For example, suppose we have two folder "cat" and "dog" and each of them has three images, how to name each three image "cat" and "dog" respectively?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: You can use os.walk(), os.path.isdir() and shutils for your purposes. Update the question with your code if you encounter any problem.